# Eclipse does not show error in the packages

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to build an android application. It was working fine, but when I built the app it showed a red cross sign in the project name (meaning there is an error). But when I open the packages with all source files it does not show any red cross signs with any of them. I tried to cleaning the project and copy it again in workspace but none of that worked.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Window -> Show View -> Problems. It'll open up a tab showing exactly whats wrong with the project.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things get cached by Eclipse and it exhibits strange behavior.  I would try shutting down eclipse and start it back up again with the -clean option.  That should fix the problem.

If not, shut your pc down and let it sit approx. 45 seconds and clear out all the memory.  Then restart and bring up Eclipse again.

Comment: If that fails you can try disabling "Automatic Builds" and deleting the bin dir in your project and then go back in and clean/build again.